# Which the best transaction isolation level can be used for this case?

Tags: postgresql

We are trying to delete and then insert the user related data while login.

Please find the below:

```
Delete from user_data where user_id=5; // user_id is not PK/Unique Key 
insert into user_data(id,data,user_id)
select id,data,5 from default_data;
```

If user login into application simultaneously 2 different request (separate transaction per request)
Case 1 If Isolation Level = Read Committed

- Request 1 (Transaction 1) -Delete the data for user 5
- Request 2 (Transaction 2) -Delete the data for user 5
- Request 1 (Transaction 1) -Insert the data for user 5
- Request 2 (Transaction 2) -Insert the data for user 5

In this scenario data becomes duplicate. Then i used Isolation level as Serializable
Case 2 If Isolation Level = Serializable

- Request 1 (Transaction 1) -Delete the data for user 5
- Request 2 (Transaction 2) -Delete the data for user 5 -- could not serialize access due to concurrent delete
- Request 1 (Transaction 1) -Insert the data for user 5
- Request 2 (Transaction 2) -Failed

In this case, it is working fine.
I could see most of the article or document prefered Isolation Level = Read Committed.

Please let me know how to handle this case

Please try the code from your end:
Execute the query:

```
create table user_data(id int primary key,data varchar(20),user_id int);
insert into user_data(id,data,user_id) values (1,'John',5),(2,'Tom',5),(3,'Jerry',5),(4,'Test',5);
select * from user_data;
```

Then create new connection and execute the below code:

**Isolation Level = Read Commit**

-- Transcation 1

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM user_data WHERE user_id=5; 
INSERT INTO user_data(id, data, user_id)
SELECT 22,'John1',5
union all
SELECT 23,'Tom1',5
union all
SELECT 24,'Jerry1',5
```

-- Transcation 2

```
BEGIN;

DELETE FROM user_data WHERE user_id=5; 

INSERT INTO user_data(id, data, user_id)
SELECT 32,'John2',5
union all
SELECT 33,'Tom2',5
union all
SELECT 34,'Jerry2',5
```

Then release the transaction 1 by executing commit;

-- Transcation 1

```
commit;
```

Then Transaction 2

-- Transcation 2

```
commit;
```

My Expected result is mentioned below :

| id | data | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32 | John2 | 5 |
| 33 | Tom2 | 5 |
| 34 | Jerry2 | 5 |

But the coming result is

| id | data | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | John1 | 5 |
| 23 | Tom1 | 5 |
| 24 | Jerry1 | 5 |
| 32 | John2 | 5 |
| 33 | Tom2 | 5 |
| 34 | Jerry2 | 5 |

Comment: Why don't you try? By the way, it's not possible that two concurrent transactions delete the same record, the second transaction has to wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: How do we lock the rows?

Comment: That's what the database does. Just give it a try and see for yourself how it works

Comment: @FrankHeikens : Could you please check my answer and correct me if anything wrong.

Comment: You don't show us your transaction boundaries. Anyway, there is only one correct solution: go and define a unique/primary key on the column. Using `SERIALIZABLE` is not only the wrong approach, but it is a much more expensive solution.

Comment: @FrankHeikens : I have updated the question with detail, please look into this

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes most of the articles are mentioning the same regarding `SERIALIZABLE` . Please let me know if any suitable solution for this.

Comment: The most efficient way to avoid duplicates it so defined a unique constraint. Everything else is just an ugly workaround that won't scale.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I could see `LOCK TABLE` is the option to lock row.

Please find the below update query:

```
LOCK TABLE user_data IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
Delete from user_data where user_id=5; // user_id is not PK/Unique Key 
insert into user_data(id,data,user_id)
select id,data,5 from default_data;
```

Comment: Why? Nobody can delete user_id 5 when your current transaction is already deleting this one. Just use a transaction, there is no need for a lock. You're not even using a transaction, or did you just didn't post it over here?

Comment: My scenario is a single user hitting the login button simultaneously so inserted the data twice. That's why i need to lock table/row to prevent the multiple insert.

Comment: No, you don't need to LOCK that table. Of course you can, but there is no need for. It's impossible to simultaneously delete a record. Just try it and you will see it.

Comment: You are correct the transaction handling in c#

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;

DELETE FROM user_data WHERE user_id=5; -- record will be locked

INSERT INTO user_data(id, data, user_id)
SELECT id, data, 5 FROM default_data;

COMMIT; -- lock will be released, other transactions can now continue
```

Comment: Second transaction will not wait for first transaction to completed, because i'm using the isolation level is read committed.

Comment: Which means second transaction worked without waiting the first transaction

Comment: Please keep in mind `user_id` is not primary key / unique key

Comment: Did you even try to test one?

Comment: Yes I tried. And Assume that some data are available in user_data before the transaction

Comment: No, you didn't, you would have seen that it's impossible to DELETE a single record at the same moment using different transactions. The commands UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT acquire ROW EXCLUSIVE lock mode on the target table. And there is no relation with a primary key or unique constraint. The record gets locked. Just start 2 separate transactions and try to delete the record. The second transaction must wait.